# How to assign different value to XML and JSON result using same class in WEB API

Tags: json, xml, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, nsjsonserialization

On Web API application i get output in the format of xml and Json results, But I stuck with one point. I get 0 and 1 from a function, While assign this value to JSON,Xml serialize class, i get output with 0 or 1 for the result, But what i really want is.

For Xml I Want

> ```
> <live>0</live>
> ```

For JSON

> [{"live":false}]

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "live", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "live", IsNullable = true)]
    public int Live { get; set; }
```

How could I do that, Give me solution

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own JSON-Contract-Resolver which handles this case. You only have to override the "CreateProperty" Method and register the Contract-Resolver in your WebApiConfig.

Why is the type of the property int? It should be bool if it only could be 0 or 1. In this case the Json Output would be correct.